# Blob data is empty when sending from ReactJS frontend to ExpressJS backend and mySQL database

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express, axios, api-design

I'm working on a ReactJS application where a user can upload a new profile picture to their user profile. My code currently pulls from a database where an image (stored as a **blob**, manually uploaded for testing) is pulled from the database and turned into an object URL to display. When the user uploads a new picture, the new picture should be written to the database along with any other information they changed. When they submit, I transform the image they uploaded into a blob and send that to the ExpressJS backend to be inserted.

My issue is that when I send my Axios.post request to the backend, the Blob is empty. I've checked on the frontend and I'm sure the Blob is being configured properly, and all of the other information is able to be retrieved from the request body.

Here is my Axios.post function:

```
const updateUser = () => {
      Axios.post('http://localhost:3002/api/changeUserInfo', {
        userID: current, // current user's ID
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        profilePicture: previewUrl
      },{
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      }).then(() => {
        console.log('successful insert');
      });
      console.log("clicked! firstName: ", firstName, " lastName: ", lastName, " email: ", email, " password: ", password, " profilePicture: ", newProfilePicture );
};
```

And here is my ExpressJS backend API:

```
app.post('/api/changeUserInfo', (req, res) => {
    
    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const userID = req.body.userID;
    const profilePicture = req.body.profilePicture;

    console.log("PROFILE PICTURE: ", profilePicture);

    const sqlInsert = "UPDATE bdb.users SET firstName = ?, lastName = ?, email = ?, password = ?, profilePicture = ? WHERE userID = ?";
    db.query(sqlInsert, [firstName, lastName, email, password, profilePicture, userID], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("SUCCESSFUL UPDATE");
            console.log(result);
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Below you can see the output in the developer console:
[image: Console output]

However, the backend recieves this as an empty object such that req.body.profilePicture = {}. Am I overlooking an incompatibility here? I know the blob is right and I know that the API picks up all of the other body information (i.e. firstName, lastName, etc are all the correct information). Any tips would be greatly appreciated!